# Access a variable declared in alertController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create an alert that prompts the user to name a song they have imported to a music sheet display app.

I have created a function for this naming process:

```
- (NSString *)nameImportedSong {
    NSString *songName;

    UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @"New Song"
                                                                              message: @"Choose a song name"
                                                                       preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"song name";
        textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    }];
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        NSArray * textfields = alertController.textFields;
        UITextField * namefield = textfields[0];
        NSString *chosenSongName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", namefield.text];

    }]];

    songName = ; // <-------------how do I assign chosenSongName to songName?

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

    return songName;

}
```

How can I assign chosenSongName from the alert into my songName variable, outside the alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use __block keyword for the variable

```
__block NSString *chosenSongName;

 [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    NSArray * textfields = alertController.textFields;
    UITextField * namefield = textfields[0];
    chosenSongName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", namefield.text];

}]];

songName = chosenSongName;
NSLog(@"chosenSongName = %@",chosenSongName);
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.